# Float left not working

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently working on a "webshop" kind of project. I am creating a product panel with a 
`float:left;` property but when I loop the products they are not coming next to each other but underneath the previous one.. What am I missing?

Code:

```
$web_string = "
<div class='product'>
<div class='image'>
    <img class='image' src='iphone.jpg' alt='iPhone' height='100%' width='100%' />
</div>
<div class='under'>
    <div class='info'>
    <ul>
        <li>iPhone</li>
        <li>iOS</li>
        <li>16 GB</li>
        <li>Black & White</li>
    </ul>
    <a href='#'>more info...</a>
    </div>
    <div class='extra'>
    <p>price: 588</p>
    <button>put in cart!</button>
    </div>
<div>
</div>";
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;

}

.product
{

    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:red;

}

.onder
{
    height:50%;
}

.afbeelding
{
    background-color: green;
}

.info
{
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

.extra
{
    background-color: purple;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
```

PHP Loop:

```
<?
echo $web_string;

    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo $web_string;
        if($i == 2)
        {
            echo "Hello World";
        }
    }
?>
```

EDIT: Changed ID's to Classes

Comment: Post the rendered HTML; we don't need the PHP for this one.

Comment: Keep in mind that HTMLElement IDs should always be unique. Always. (And shouldn't start with numbers.)

Answer (score 5):

You're using CSS ID selector which can be used to point only ONE element. So the float property is applied only on the first one. Use class instead : `<div class='product'>` and then in your CSS : `.product { float: left; }`
Same thing for "image" and "under"

Comment: Damn you're right.. I feel very stupid now I realise this.. Guess I'm not fully awake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jfiddle fix:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/u5v4V/1/)

Had to add `float: left;` on `image` and `under` ID too

```
#image {
    float: left;
}

#under {
    float: left;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you needed